# ¿Cómo hacer visible un botón desde un layout diferente? Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

Tengo el layout principal, y otros 4 layouts(1...4), en el principal tengo tres botones (1 visible y los otros dos no), y en el ultimo layout tengo un boton.

Lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click en ese boton (Layout 4, unicamente desde el 4to) regrese al principal y se haga visible uno de los botones del layout principal.

Intente hacerlo con IntentForResult pero al pasar del principal al layout 1 y presionar back, ya se hace visible el boton y es lo que no quiero.

Comment: ¿Para llegar al layout 4 tienes que pasar por los 3 anteriores o puedes ir desde la actividad principal? Otra cosa, ¿puedes poner el código del startActivityForResult  que dices que note funciona? Yo cuando he trabajado con este método me ha ido, lo que pasa que tienes que utilizar un parámetro para indicar desde donde vuelves, seguramente por eso no ha hecho lo que tu quieres

Comment: Pon el código que tienes para que podamos ayudarte